# Querying cached records in Rails seems slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm doing a query based suggestion API in Rails, with suggestions being returned to the user as they type. In order to avoid hitting the database too often, I decided to cache the records.

```rb
def cached_values
  Rails.cache.fetch(:values_cached, expires_in: 1.day) do
    Table.verified.select(:value).all
  end
end

cached_values
=>
[#<Table:0x000056406fc70370 id: nil, value: "xxx">,
 #<Table:0x000056406fc77f80 id: nil, value: "xxx">,
 #<Table:0x000056406fc77d00 id: nil, value: "xxx">

 ...
```

I'm aware it's not a good practice to cache ActiveRecord entries, but the "verified" scope is relatively small (~6k rows) and I want to query it further. So when a call to the API is made, I query the cached values (simplified, the real one is sanitized):

```
def query_cached(query)
  cached_values.where("value LIKE '%#{query}%'").to_a
end
```

The issue here is that I have tested both cached and uncached queries, and the later has better performance. Setting `Rails.logger.level = 0`, I noticed the cached query still logs a database query:

```
pry(main)> query_cached("a")
  Table Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "table"."value" FROM "table" WHERE "table"."verified" = TRUE AND (value LIKE '%a%')
```

My guess is that the cached search is both opening a connection to the database and loading the cached records, taking more time but being effectively useless. Is there any reliable way to check that?
If the cache is just slower, maybe it is still worth keeping it and preventing too many connections to the database.

Benchmark for 10000 queries each:

```
       user     system      total        real
uncached 20.110681   0.369983  20.480664 ( 26.935934)
cached 23.750934   0.753414  24.504348 ( 34.198694)
```

Comment: This feels like a potential AB question to me. The *real* question sounds like "how can I make these queries faster", not necessarily "how can I cache a partial database query"?

Comment: Of course it's still making a database query, though -- because how else is `where("value LIKE '%#{query}%'")` going to function?

Comment: The answer is probably that you should set up / optimise your database indexes.

Comment: The point is that the `WHERE` query is being made over the cached `cached_values` method, which should store records for a day. If that is true, as I understand it,  then the where method shouldn't open a connection to the database, but rather use already cached data

Comment: No, you're trying to outthink your DB here. If you do end up caching those records, you'll end up with an array with 6k records in it which you can't further query with ActiveRecord. Caches are appropriate for static sets of data which do not need further refinement, or which are prohibitive to load directly. Set up DB indexes, forget the caching, and call it a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to note that [`all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-all) doesn't return all records in an array. Instead it returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. Such a relation represents a database query that might be called later or that can be extended by more conditions like, for example, `.where("value LIKE '%#{query}%'")`. If `all` already returned an array of records then you would not be able to add the additional condition with `.where("value LIKE '%#{query}%'")` to it because `where` doesn't exist on arrays.

Because you only cached the Relation that represents a database query that can be run by calling a method that needs the actual records (like `each`, `to_a`, `first`) but hasn't run yet, the caching is useless in this case.

Additionally, I would argue that caching is not useful in the context of this example at all because you would need to cache different values for each different user input. That means if the user searched for `foo` then you can cache that result but if another user then searches for `bar` you would still need to run another query to the database. Only if two users search for the *same* string the cache might be useful.

In your example, a full-text index in the database might be the better choice.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I thought since the `cached_values` method returned a list of model objects such as `#<Table:0x000056406fc70370 id: nil, value: "xxx">` - note that "value" is an actual database value - data was already fetched and could be queried further without opening connections, but that does make sense

Comment: When calling `cached_values` there was still a `Relation` returned. but when calling something in the IRB or Rails console then `inspect` is called on the return value to output the return value in the console. Calling `inspect` on a `Relation` triggers the actual call to the database.